# Almost Vs. Hardly

Tags: differences

According to [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hardly) **hardly** has 4 meanings. And I was wondering: is there any difference between these two sentences? In what meaning the word **hardly** is used here if you can use it in this way at all:

- My car has **almost** run into the crowd.
- My car has **hardly** run into the crowd.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two sentences are very different.

> My car has almost run into the crowd.

Means the car has very nearly run into the crowd, but it has not. You may have turned the car away at the last minute, it may have been stopped by something, or you might be referring to a moment in time *just before* the car ran into the crowd.

> My car has hardly run into the crowd.

Means the car has run into the crowd, but only just a little bit. Perhaps you've only hit one or two pedestrians at that point in time, but most of them are unharmed.

Answer (score 0):

> My car almost [ran] into the bog.

This has the sense that 'had conditions been just slightly different, it would have run into the bog'. Perhaps the brakes had failed, and it freewheeled but stopped just short of the bog, or perhaps kids were messing with the brakes but you caught them just in time.

> I hardly [drove] my car on your precious lawn.

This can have two senses:

(a) with 'hardly' modifying 'drove' (restricting the claimed amount of driving that took place on the lawn (I caused hardly any damage)

(b) with 'hardly' modifying the entire sentence (There's no way I drove my car on your precious lawn - how could you think such a thing?)